# Simultaneous validation of movement of multiple pawns on a 2D grid

Tags: algorithm, optimization, logic

Let’s say that we have a 2D grid with pawns on it, like a game board.

-Pawns can move in any direction by one cell at a time.

-Pawns cannot occupy the same space or pass through each other (swap places).

If only one pawn moved at a time it would be simple. 
However, I want all pawns to move at the same time, so all moves need to be checked before anything is committed, since some moves depend on others.

For example: 
Pawn A wants to move into a cell occupied by pawn B. 
We need to check if pawn B moves. A can only move if B is going to free it’s cell.

I’m trying to figure out how to handle such a problem in a decently optimized way.

Everything I came up so far inevitably leads either to infinite loops or fails to solve for all pawns.

My best approach to far is to list all desired movements and iterate through them. 
If one movement requires another movement to be solved I create a chain until I encounter a movement that can be solved, and solve all movements accordingly, going back in the chain. 
However, this leads to problems if pawns are in a circle.

Answer (score 0):

With this problem, only the end location of the pawns are of interest. It does not matter where they came from. So the only thing what you need to check if that the pawns in their end position have a conflict with one another.

When so, you have a situation that 2 or more pawns want to occupy the same location. If so, you can do 2 things:
1. Solve the problem with the pawn by giving them the option to move to a different location (not occupied by any pawn yet).
2. Reverse all moves.

Sounds to me you are traveling back in time by saying: One could not move so it needs to go back but this location is now occupied so that pawn needs to move back, etc. If that is the case, you are actually saying that your pawns are NOT moving all at the same time..

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a grid (2d array) with all the pawns
2. For each pawn create an array (movement) with all the possible movements (in this case 8 moves per pawns, assuming it has to move)
3. Move all the pawns which have more than one movement option in the movement array, regardless of validity by randomly picking a movement from the movement array.
4. For all the pawns that end up on a valid place remove all entries from the movement array except the place it is occupying.
5. For the invalid pawns remove the invalid location from the movement array
6. Loop to step 3 again until every entry in the movement array only has one movement option.

If a pawn has an empty movement array it is stuck with no possible movements. It might be wise to check for movement again of these pawns after step 6 is completed.

I think this algorithms solves almost all situations and I think it is relative efficient.

Nice thing is that you can easily integrate other pieces, just give them another movement option array.